# I selected a different quest and now I can't get back to the quest I was on

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What goes missing when changing your quest in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71760/what-goes-missing-when-changing-your-quest-in-diablo-3)
>   [Can I go back to do a quest and then come back to where I was?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72063/can-i-go-back-to-do-a-quest-and-then-come-back-to-where-i-was)

I had quite a few items I had been saving for my husband who had just started playing. I was in Act 2 working in the sewers of Caldeum but hadn't quite met the gem artisan yet.

I joined my husband's game just to see how the feature worked and I gave him some gear. Now I'm stuck, I can't seem to just 'leave' party with him and waystation back to my game. All my previous waystations are gone, it seems as though I erased it all?

I contacted Blizzard and their response was basically that they didn't deal with in-game questions like this, so I've been searching everywhere for answers. It seems people are able to group per say and then leave party so how do they get back to where they were in-game?

Has anyone experienced something similar, any information would be helpful.

Comment: What goes missing when changing your quest: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71760/what-goes-missing-when-changing-your-quest-in-diablo-3

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example it sounds like you are farther ahead than he is.

You will have lost all the checkpoints in your current quest and will have to start over from where the last major quest event occurred.

You can change the quest you are on before you enter the game by clicking on the "Change Quest" button and selecting the quest point that is the farthest down when scrolling. When you re-enter the game at that point it will have given you the waypoints up to that quest starting area.